# How to determine the difference in (leading) spaces using Git

Tags: git, diff, whitespace

Some refactoring work resulted in decreased complexity and associated decrease in indentation of code. It's straightforward to show the number of *changed files and added/removed lines* in Git.

### Question

**What is the best way to display the difference in (leading) spaces for changed lines between two Git commits?**

### Example

This is simple:

```
$ git show --stat HEAD^..HEAD | grep changed
11 files changed, 210 insertions(+), 235 deletions(-)
```

Something like this is what I'm looking for:

```
$ <command-here> HEAD^..HEAD
846 leading spaces removed
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to accomplish your goal is to use [`pronto`](https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto) which is designed to run a battery of code metrics against your changes, commits, and Pull Requests. Or to use a service such as [Code Climate Quality](https://codeclimate.com/quality/).

---

Get the files for each commit, total up the leading spaces, and subtract.

`git cat-file blob <rev>:<file>` will show a file from a given commit.

`git ls-tree --name-only -r <rev>` will list of files in a commit without checking them out. We can use `xargs` to put them together and get a stream of all the lines in a commit.

Now we need to stream this to something. Git won't total up leading spaces for you, you need a tool for that. Here's a simple example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

TAB_SIZE = 8

puts ARGF.each.sum { |line|
  # Skip blank and comment-only lines.
  if match = %r{(^[ \t]+)[^#\s]}.match(line)
    match[1].count(" ") + (match[1].count("\t") * TAB_SIZE)
  else
    0
  end
}
```

Gluing it all together with `xargs`...

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD | xargs -I'{}' git cat-file blob HEAD:'{}' | total_leading_spaces
```

Note that there are much better code metrics out there to measure complexity. For example, [`flog`](http://ruby.sadi.st/Flog.html) will measure your [ABC Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Software_Metric).